# Getting the quantity of currently available items

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a simple application in java and I am stuck in one sql statement. Lets say that I have two tables called `items` with attributes `itemId` and `quantity` and `orderDetails` also with attributes `itemId` and `quantity`. In the table Items I keep all the items and in orderDetails table I keep an itemId and quantity which was hired out to the customers. The goal is to write a sql statement which returns table with itemId and quantity of items which are currently available. I tried it several ways but I did not find a proper solution. (I am very very new in sql). This is one of them which I tried:

```
SELECT itemId, quantity - (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM orderdetails GROUP BY itemId)
FROM items, orderdetails 
WHERE orderdetails.itemid = items.itemid;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Egor why editing so eagerly?..

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev - Just formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could use correlated query (which IIRC should generally be avoided):

```
select 
   items.itemid, 
   items.quantity - 
       (select sum(quantity) 
          from orderdetails 
          where orderdetails.itemid = items.itemid group by itemid) left
from items;
```

Or you could join two tables:

```
select items.itemid, quantity - total.q left from
items, 
  (select itemid, sum(quantity) q from
   orderdetails
   group by itemid) total
where items.itemid = total.itemid (+);
```

Comment: Forgot to handle `NULL`. Just call `NVL` in the second subtraction operand.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide some table data, for example:

```
select items.itemId, items.quantity - sum(quantity)
from items, orderdetails 
where orderdetails.itemid = items.itemid
group by items.itemId, items.quantity
```